# Spring Long.parseLong() gives The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring

Hi I'm working on Spring Boot project, I get String number from request and I want to parse it to Long to save to database,

This is my parseLong code,

```
Long.parseLong(customerId);
```

I got error

> The type com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3 cannot be resolved. It
> is indirectly referenced from required .class files

[image]

I think I did it correctly. It's very simple function. But I do not understand what happened.

Please help.

Comment: Compiler seems confused. Try doing a clean build.

Comment: what is the type of customerId? show the code.

Comment: @ch271828n of course String, '@RequestParam String customerId'

Comment: @HikaruShindo could you plz give a minimal reproducible sample

Comment: @ch271828n Just declare String and parse to Long then I got that error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It takes me 4 hours to solve this by removing

> import com.mysql.cj.x.protobuf.MysqlxDatatypes.Scalar.String;

That I have not noticed when I came.

Comment: That's why I say, give a minimal reproducible sample :)